# How to localize reStructuredText and Sphinx messages?

Tags: localization, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am writing documentation in language other than English (actually Slovak). I do not want the words like *Content*, *Note*, *Caution* to appear in my Slovak documentation, instead of that, I want to have *Obsah*, *Poznámka*, *Pozor*.

After some time googling, I was unable to find a way to do it. Could you give me an advice please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you conf.py you can set the language in this section:

```
# The language for content autogenerated by Sphinx. Refer to documentation
# for a list of supported languages.
language = 'nl'
```

The [list of supported languages](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html), however, does not show support for Slovak yet. But there are good instructions to [create your own internationalization files](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/intl.html) so that you can ad Slovak to the list.

Comment: The link for internationalization above is no longer valid. Here is the (currently) correct link for [restructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/howto/i18n.html) and [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/intl.html), which do *not* appear to use the same mechanism.

Comment: Thank you @GeorgeBoukeas! I've updated the link in the answer.

Comment: If this doesn't work, it may be due to bugs in the theme being used. For example it's what happens to me using the "Book" theme.